# What is the difference between "Cooperative Pathfinding" and "Multi-Agent Pathfinding"?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, multi-agent

So recently I was reading a research paper titled "Cooperative Pathfinding" by David Silver which mentioned that Cooperative Pathfinding is a multi-agent path planning problem ...

From my understanding both the terms seem to be the same to me since they mean the same, so thus not able to make out as to what I'm missing out on. It would be really great if someone could explain the difference to me between the two terms or provide/pinpoint me to some resources that would help up clear the confusion. Thanks!